# Deploying code First app to AppHarbor

Tags: entity-framework, appharbor

I have deployed an app to appharbor ,enabled package restore and I can see the packages are being restored , but the build still doesn't find the EntityFramework dll and some others.
Here is a part of the log:

Successfully installed 'DataAnnotationsExtensions 1.1.0.0'.
         Successfully installed 'DotNetOpenAuth.AspNet 4.0.3.12153'.
         Successfully installed 'DotNetOpenAuth.OAuth.Consumer 4.0.3.12153'.
         Successfully installed 'DotNetOpenAuth.Core 4.0.3.12153'.
         Successfully installed 'DotNetOpenAuth.OAuth.Core 4.0.3.12153'.
         Successfully installed 'DotNetOpenAuth.OpenId.Core 4.0.3.12153'.
         Successfully installed 'DotNetOpenAuth.OpenId.RelyingParty 4.0.3.12153'.
         Successfully installed 'EntityFramework 5.0.0'.

Primary reference "EntityFramework".
     2>C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.targets(1578,5): warning MSB3245: Could not resolve this reference. Could not locate the assembly "EntityFramework"

What can be wrong ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to manually change the references , and now it works . It was looking in ..\packages
It should be "packages".It looks like appharbor has some problem with EntityFramework 5 , I had to change to 4.3.1 to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the application is looking for the dll in the wrong place. Can you verify that the project reference to EntityFramework is pointing to the dll in your "packages" directory (rather than the GAC'ed assembly)?

Another developer [had a similar issue](http://support.appharbor.com/discussions/problems/6250-build-error-could-not-resolve-this-reference-could-not-locate-the-assembly-entityframework) and resolved it by fixing the reference paths.

Comment: I have checked and the HintPath looks ok. EntityFramework its not the only problem . All dlls that came with nuget are having the same problem and some of them are not in the GAC.